Sorting results from Get-MailboxFolderPermission
I would like to sort the results of Get-MailboxFolderPermission by the User property on Exchange Online PowerShell but it has not been working.
Results Screenshot
The PowerShell command I have tried:

Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity 'xyz@abc.com:\Calendar' | Sort-Object -Property User

The User property is of type Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderUserId and the actual name is in the User.DisplayName property, so I tried to sort by User.DisplayName but it did not work either.

Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity 'xyz@abc.com:\Calendar' | Sort-Object -Property User.DisplayName


You'd need a scriptblock Sort-Object -Property User.DisplayName should be Sort-Object -Property { $_.User.DisplayName }

The script block worked, thank you!

You need to use a scriptblock to evaluate expressions such as accessing a nested property and sorting by its value (.User.DisplayName) for each object. See Example 6 from the cmdlet's documentation and Notes from about Calculated Properties.
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity 'xyz@abc.com:\Calendar' |
    Sort-Object -Property { $_.User.DisplayName }

